# Boost function assignment throws exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

Boost::function is throwing me exceptions one out of ten times when I try to assign one function1 to another function1.

Task is a typedef for `boost::function1<void, void*>`.

Here is the specific code:

```
    // the Task object sent in as Task task
    void Sleeper(void* arg)
    {
        int32_t sleepTime = *(int32_t*)arg;

        SleepCurrentThread((int32_t)sleepTime);
    }

    struct ThreadInfo
    {
        ThreadInfo() : mState(DETACHED), mTask(NULL), mArg(NULL)
        { }

        ThreadState mState;
        Task mTask;
        void* mArg;
    };

    Thread::Thread(Task task, void* arg, IMemoryAllocator& allocator, ILogManager& logger) : mAllocator(allocator), mLogger(logger)
    {
        mThreadInfo = (ThreadInfo*) mAllocator.Allocate(sizeof(ThreadInfo));  // simnple heap allocation

        mThreadInfo->mArg = arg;
        mThreadInfo->mState = Thread::RUNNING;
        mThreadInfo->mTask = task;     //<--------- throws... sometimes


        mHandle = _CreateThread(&Run, (void*)mThreadInfo);
        if (!mHandle)
            Detach();


    }
```

I specificly tracked it down in the boost function_template.hpp to the assignment operator, on this code, where it ultimately throws:

```
// Assignment from another BOOST_FUNCTION_FUNCTION
    BOOST_FUNCTION_FUNCTION& operator=(const BOOST_FUNCTION_FUNCTION& f)
    {
      if (&f == this)
        return *this;

      this->clear();
      BOOST_TRY {
        this->assign_to_own(f);        // <--- throws, and then line below re-throws
      } BOOST_CATCH (...) {
        vtable = 0;
        BOOST_RETHROW;
      }
      BOOST_CATCH_END
      return *this;
    }
```

Why is this? Is there anything easily spotted that is wrong with my code? Is there anything else needed?

Thanks

EDIT: I know I will be asked to use boost::threads, but I'm trying out my own wrapper around win32/pthread, (for fun)

Comment: Try allocating your `ThreadInfo` with a plain old `new` instead of `IMemoryAllocator` and see if the exceptions go away.

Comment: @ecatmur: No, it's `exception::what` ;-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `struct` has a non-trivial constructor, but you don't call it. It leaves the `Task` member uninitialized. To initialize it, either allocate the whole object with `new`, or use placement new to initialize it as follows:

```
    void *mem = mAllocator.Allocate(sizeof(ThreadInfo));  // simnple heap allocation
    mThreadInfo = new(mem) ThreadInfo; // placement new

    mThreadInfo->mArg = arg;
    mThreadInfo->mState = Thread::RUNNING;
    mThreadInfo->mTask = task;
```

Placement new constructs an object in an already allocated raw (uninitialized) memory.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Note that before deallocating, you should also call the destructor: `mThreadInfo->~ThreadInfo()`. Also the above code is not exception safe, i.e. if `ThreadInfo` constructor throws an exception then you should deallocate the memory *without* calling the destructor.

Comment: And all this illustrates how the low-level stuff is hard, and why you should use existing high-level libraries.